# I am trying to write a trigger in parse.com but some error

Tags: javascript, database, parse-platform, cloud, parse-cloud-code

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("StatusTable", function(request) {
        var deviceName = request.object.get("deviceName");
        var lastSeen = request.object.get("entryTime");
        var sectionName = request.object.get("sectionName");

        var LastSeen = Parse.Object.extend("LastSeen");
        var query = new Parse.Query(LastSeen);
        query.equalTo("deviceName", deviceName);

        query.first().then(function(result) {
            result.put("lastSeen", lastSeen);
            result.put("sectionName", sectionName);
            result.save();
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
);
```

I have two tables in parse. `StatusTable` and `LastSeen` table.I need to write a trigger which updates `lastSeen` and `sectionName` columns of `LastSeen` table when a successful insert has occurred in `StatusTable` corresponding to the `deviceName`.This code is not working.

**StatusTable**

[image]

**LastSeenTable**

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: The trigger is not working. Only the 'StatusTable' is getting updated.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or it's just not getting updated?

Comment: No error messages,  The table 'LastSeen' is not getting updated.

Comment: what does `put` method suppose to do ?? What happened to `set` ??

Comment: save `result` with callback so you can identify exect problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `Object` documentation: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html

There is no `put()` method. Try using `set()` instead:

```
query.first().then(function(result) {
    result.set("lastSeen", lastSeen);
    result.set("sectionName", sectionName);
    result.save();
});
```

Also, are you sure you want your query to use `first` instead of `find`? Just to ensure that you are always updating the object that you want.

Comment: I am new to this cloud. Could you please tell me where can I see the output of 'alert' function. In JS we use console.log, do we have anything as such here?